# Memory error while trying to get list of files from the directory and storing it in the spreadsheet

Tags: python

I have downloaded the code from Google bard to get the list of files from the directory and sub directory to store it in a spreadsheet.

I am getting a memory error.

My question: write a program in python to list of files in the directory and sub directory and store the file names in the spreadsheet with index, header, path of the file and file name in separate columns.

Code given by Google Bard:

```
import os
import openpyxl

def list_files(directory):
  """Lists all files in the given directory and subdirectories.

  Args:
    directory: The directory to list.

  Returns:
    A list of all files in the given directory and subdirectories.
  """

  files = []
  for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
      files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
  return files

def save_to_spreadsheet(files, spreadsheet_path):
  """Saves the given list of files to the given spreadsheet.

  Args:
    files: A list of files.
    spreadsheet_path: The path to the spreadsheet.
  """

  wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
  ws = wb.active

  # Write the header row.
  ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Index"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Header"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=3).value = "Path"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=4).value = "File Name"

  # Write the file data.
  for i, file in enumerate(files):
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=1).value = i + 1
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=2).value = "File"
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=3).value = file
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=4).value = os.path.basename(file)

  # Save the spreadsheet.
  wb.save(spreadsheet_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Get the directory to list.
  directory = "/path/to/directory"

  # List the files in the directory and subdirectories.
  files = list_files(directory)

  # Save the file names to a spreadsheet.
  spreadsheet_path = "/path/to/spreadsheet.xlsx"
  save_to_spreadsheet(files, spreadsheet_path)
```

Error:-

```
E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\venv\listoffiles_storing_excel.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\venv\listoffiles_storing_excel.py", line 52, in <module>
    files = list_files(directory)
  File "E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\venv\listoffiles_storing_excel.py", line 17, in list_files
    files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
MemoryError
```

Please give me a solution to overcome with this.
Thank you so much.

Comment: You're appending to `files` while you're trying to iterate it. This is an infinite loop until you run out of memory.

Comment: You may want to try learning Python from reputable resources rather than relying on AI

Comment: i ran the above script. It is storing only one folder file names and leaving behind all other folders and its file name. I do not know what i am missing to get all the file names and store it in the excel.

Comment: i ran the above script. It is storing only one folder file names and leaving behind all other folders and its file name. I do not know what i am missing to get all the file names and store it in the excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done more easily with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Based on your second answer, you could use something like this:

```py
import os
import os.path

import pandas as pd

starting_location = r'D:\education'
output_file = r'D:\education\spreadsheet.xlsx'

def get_flat_file_list(starting_point):
    for (current_directory, _, filenames) in os.walk(starting_point):
        for current_file in filenames:
            yield (
                os.path.basename(current_directory),
                current_directory, 
                os.path.join(current_directory, current_file),
                current_file
                )


header_columns = ('Folder Name', 'Directory Path', 'File Path', 'File Name')
files_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(get_flat_file_list(starting_location), columns=header_columns)

files_df.to_excel(output_file, index_label="Index", merge_cells=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
files = []
for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
  for file in files:
    files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

You're using the name `files` for the empty list, but then you **also** use the name `files` for the third return result from `os.walk()`.

So you keep appending `files` to itself, forever, until you run out of memory.

Use a different name for `files = []`, like this:

```
allfiles = []
for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
   for file in files:
       allfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
return allfiles
```

Comment: i have changed the code to below. Will it work now?

 filestest = []
  for root, _, filestest in os.walk(directory):
    for file in filestest:
      filestest.append(os.path.join(root, file))
  return file

Comment: @vivekrajagopalan No, because you're **still** using the same name for both things.  You need to use **different** names.  You renamed **both** of them to `filestest`.

Comment: i changed the name as below but its not listing all the files in the spreadsheet. It is storing just for one folder and leaving behind all.
  filestest = []
  for root, _, file in os.walk(directory):
    for file in filestest:
      filestest.append(os.path.join(root, file))
  return file

Comment: @vivekrajagopalan Well, now you're reusing the name `file` to mean two different things.

Comment: i ran the above script. It is storing only one folder file names and leaving behind all other folders and its file name. I do not know what i am missing to get all the file names and store it in the excel.

Comment: i ran the above script. It is storing only one folder file names and leaving behind all other folders and its file name. I do not know what i am missing to get all the file names and store it in the excel.

Comment: @vivekrajagopalan See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much John Gordon.
Now the whole code is working and posted the screenshot for the same.
Below the full and corrected code.

```
  [![import os
import openpyxl

def list_files(directory):
  """Lists all files in the given directory and subdirectories.

  Args:
    directory: The directory to list.

  Returns:
    A list of all files in the given directory and subdirectories.
  """

  allfiles = \[\]
  for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
      for file in files:
          allfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
  return allfiles

def save_to_spreadsheet(files, spreadsheet_path):
  """Saves the given list of files to the given spreadsheet.

  Args:
    files: A list of files.
    spreadsheet_path: The path to the spreadsheet.
  """

  wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
  ws = wb.active

  # Write the header row.
  ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Index"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Header"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=3).value = "Path"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=4).value = "File Name"

  # Write the file data.
  for i, file in enumerate(files):
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=1).value = i + 1
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=2).value = "File"
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=3).value = file
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=4).value = os.path.basename(file)

  # Save the spreadsheet.
  wb.save(spreadsheet_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Get the directory to list.
  directory = "D:\\education"

  # List the files in the directory and subdirectories.
  files = list_files(directory)

  # Save the file names to a spreadsheet.
  spreadsheet_path = "D:\\education\\spreadsheet.xlsx"
  save_to_spreadsheet(files, spreadsheet_path)][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and modified the code as per my needs.
Hope it will help everyone.

```
import os
import openpyxl
import time

def list_files(directory):
  """Lists all files in the given directory and subdirectories.

  Args:
    directory: The directory to list.

  Returns:
    A list of all files in the given directory and subdirectories.
  """

  allfiles = []
  for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
      allfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
  return allfiles

def save_to_spreadsheet(files, spreadsheet_path):
  """Saves the given list of files to the given spreadsheet.

  Args:
    files: A list of files.
    spreadsheet_path: The path to the spreadsheet.
  """

  start_time = time.time()

  wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
  ws = wb.active

  # Write the header row.
  ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Index"
  #ws.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Header"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Folder Name"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=3).value = "Directory Path"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=4).value = "File Path"
  ws.cell(row=1, column=5).value = "File Name"
 # ws.cell(row=1, column=7).value = "Time Taken (seconds)"

  # Write the file data.
  for i, file in enumerate(files):
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=1).value = i + 1
    #ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=2).value = "File"
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=2).value = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file))
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=3).value = os.path.dirname(file)
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=4).value = file
    ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=5).value = os.path.basename(file)

    # Calculate the time taken to write the file.
    #write_time = time.time() - start_time
    #start_time = time.time()

    #ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=7).value = write_time

  # Save the spreadsheet.
  wb.save(spreadsheet_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Get the directory to list.
  directory = "D:\\education"

  # List the files in the directory and subdirectories.
  files = list_files(directory)

  # Save the file names to a spreadsheet.
  spreadsheet_path = "D:\\education\\spreadsheet.xlsx"
  save_to_spreadsheet(files, spreadsheet_path)
```